# Find $\Im((\cos 12^\circ +i \sin 12^\circ +\cos 48^\circ+i\sin 48 ^\circ )^6)$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Find $\Im((\cos 12^\circ +i \sin 12^\circ +\cos 48^\circ+i\sin 48
>  ^\circ )^6)$.

I've solved this problem but I think I've taken the long way to do this, so I am asking if there's some slick way to solve this.

**That's how I solved it**:
I've applied the identity $\cos 48 +\cos 12=2\cos\left(\cfrac{48+12}{2}\right)\cdot \cos\left(\cfrac{48-12}{2}\right)=2 \cos 30 \cdot \cos18 =\sqrt{3}\cdot \cos 18 $

and the same for $\sin (12)+\sin(48)=2\sin (30)\cdot \cos(18)=\cos(18) $

Thus I have $\Im((\cos 12^\circ +i \sin 12^\circ +\cos 48^\circ+i\sin 48 ^\circ )^6)=\Im((\sqrt{3} \cos 18 +i \cos 18)^6)$

In the end I've applied the Binomial Theorem
(if it's necessary, I will edit including this step ), however this was really a painfull process.
So is there some slick way to solve this ?

**My thought:**
I think there must be some way to turn the above expression into something like $(\cos\theta +i \sin \theta )^6$, that would be pretty neat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close. The argument of the expression is equivalent to
$$
\left(\mathrm{e}^{i\frac{\pi}{15}}+\mathrm{e}^{i\frac{4\pi}{15}}\right)^6 = \mathrm{e}^{i\frac{2\pi}{5}}\left(1+\mathrm{e}^{i\frac{\pi}{5}}\right)^6
$$
then you can extract $\mathrm{e}^{i\pi/10}$ to find
$$
\mathrm{e}^{i\frac{2\pi}{5}+i\frac{6\pi}{10}}\left(\mathrm{e}^{-i\frac{\pi}{10}}+\mathrm{e}^{i\frac{\pi}{10}}\right)^6
$$
then knowing that
$$
\cos (x) =\frac{\mathrm{e}^{ix}+\mathrm{e}^{-ix}}{2}\implies 2\cos (x) = \mathrm{e}^{ix}+\mathrm{e}^{-ix}
$$
I can re-write as
$$
\mathrm{e}^{i\frac{2\pi}{5}+i\frac{3\pi}{5}}\left(2\cos (\frac{\pi}{10}) \right)^6
$$
you should be good to go right?

Comment: Well,not really.What should be the best way to simplify $\left(2 \cos (\pi/20)\right)^6 $ ? Do I transform it in $\cos (\cfrac{\pi/10}{2})$ and then apply the identity for $\cos(x/2)$ ?Btw this approach is pretty neat ,thank you !

Comment: You can do whatever is required to simplify it. It is a simpler to reduce from here. Alternatively you could expand extract one term completely (at the point where I obtain the $\cos $ relation) and use standard Binomal expansion. Which you could also have achieved from the original statement. I hope it helps.

Comment: Note: $\mathrm{e}^{a} = \mathrm{e}^{i\pi/30}$ then we can see that $$\left(\mathrm{e}^a+\mathrm{e}^{4a}\right)^6 = \mathrm{e}^{6a}\left(1+\mathrm{e}^{4a-a}\right)^6$$ hope this helps.

Comment: ah you are right.

Comment: Note to self $\frac{2\pi}{30}\neq \frac{\pi}{30}$!

Answer (score 2):

Let me try.

$$2^6\cos^6 18(\cos 30 + i\sin 30 )^6 = 64\cos^6 18 (\cos 180 + i^6\sin 180) = -64\cos^6 18.$$

Comment: This is funny because this is also what I got on my first try, but apparently it's wrong. The answer should be 0.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:
$$\Im \left(\left(\cos 12^\circ +i \sin 12^\circ +\cos 48^\circ+i\sin 48 ^\circ \right)^6\right)$$
$$=\large{\Im\left(\left(e^{i\frac{\pi}{15}}+e^{i\frac{4\pi}{15}}\right)^6\right)}$$